# Compare MySql date with system date using java

Tags: java, mysql

I try to compare date stored in mysql table column with current date using java.

I want to check whether the date is more than 3 days from the date which is stored in database table, it shows the error...

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EDUCATION_MANAGEMENT";
        try
        {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date crrDate=new Date();
            crrDate=sdf.parse(sdf.format(crrDate));
            Date dbDate=new Date();
            System.out.println("Current Date ::: "+crrDate);
            String userid="root";
            String password="admin";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,userid,password);
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            String getDate="select t_create_date from student_account where stud_id=100";
            rs=stmt.executeQuery(getDate);
            if(rs.next())
            {
                dbDate=sdf.parse(rs.getString("t_create_date"));
                System.out.println("Database Date ::: "+dbDate);
            }
            if(crrDate.compareTo(dbDate)>3)
            {
                System.out.println("Date is less than 3");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Date is Greater than 3");
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException sqle)
        {
            System.out.println("Error occured ::: "+sqle);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error occured ::: "+e);
        }


    }
```

Please tell me the code....

Comment: will be easier to help if you show us your current code here.

Comment: Hai Andy, I have attached my code now... I don't know whether it is  correct or not.... Please Help me....

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has pretty good date functions, you could just run

```
select t_create_date < now() - interval 3 day as more_than_3_days_ago
  from student_account 
 where stud_id=100
```

then just get the boolean value more_than_3_days_ago and thats your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, Andreas' answer will serve your purpose. If you want to do it in java, you will have to extract the data as Date Object
`rs.getDate("DATE_COLUMN")` and do the comparison.

You will probably find [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) very useful for comparisons.